# Notice: Undefined index in php for displaying image from database

Tags: php, html

i am working on kind of social networking type of project in php but stucked somewhere to display use image from database & getting this

Notice: Undefined index: usimg in C:\wamp\www\collegenetwrking\profileleft.php on line 19

profile.php

```
<?php
include("header.php");
include("profilesql.php");
include("friends.php"); 
?>
<center>
<div class=container>
<div class=container>

<!-- head --><!-- navigation menu -->
<?php include("head.php"); ?>
<?php
include("menu.php"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile ORDER BY RAND()");
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
      if($row["userid"] != $_SESSION["stuid"] )
{ 
$img[$i] = $row["image"];
$uid[$i] = $row["userid"];
$city[$i] = $row['city'];
$i++;
  }
  }
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stuacc where id");  

$strec = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stuacc WHERE email='$_SESSION[logid]' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($strec))
  {
$_SESSION["stuid"] =  $row["id"];

  }

$colrec = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE userid='$_SESSION[stuid]' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($colrec))
  {
$cname = $row["coluni"];
  }

$acrec1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stuacc WHERE id='$uid[0]' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($acrec1))
  {
      $stid1 = $row["id"];
$name1 = $row["firstname"];
$gen1= $row["iam"];
  }

  $acrec2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stuacc WHERE id='$uid[1]' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($acrec2))
  {
          $stid2 = $row["id"];
$name2 = $row["firstname"];
$gen2= $row["iam"];
  }

  $acrec3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stuacc WHERE id='$uid[2]' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($acrec3))
  {
          $stid3 = $row["id"];
$name3 = $row["firstname"];
$gen3= $row["iam"];
  }

  $acrec4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stuacc WHERE id='$uid[3]' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($acrec4))
  {
          $stid4 = $row["id"];
$name4 = $row["firstname"];
$gen4= $row["iam"];
  }
?>


<div style="padding: 10px; text-align: left;">
<!-- body  content -->

    <table width="100%" height="382" border="0" >
  <tr>
    <td width="16%" rowspan="9" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php include("profileleft.php"); ?></td>
    <td width="55%" rowspan="9" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"><strong>Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["logid"]; ?></strong></th>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Number of visitors:
              <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
 $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
   else
 $_SESSION['views']=1;
 echo $_SESSION['views']; 
 ?>
          </strong></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
         <?php if(isset($cname)) { ?> <td><strong>College Name : </strong><b><?php echo $cname ; ?></b></td><?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width=100%>

        <tr valign=top align=center>
          <td colspan="4" align="left"><strong>Request Friends</strong></td>
          </tr>
        <tr valign=top align=center>
            <td><a href="friendsprofile.php?fid=<?php echo $stid1 ; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $img[0] ; ?>" width="100" height="150" border="0" alt=""><br />
             <?php echo $name1 ; ?><br />

            </a><br></td>
            <td><a href="friendsprofile.php?fid=<?php echo $stid2 ; ?>""><img src="<?php echo $img[1] ; ?>" width="100" height="150" border="0" alt=""><br />
              <?php echo $name2 ; ?>
            </a><br></td>
            <td><a href="friendsprofile.php?fid=<?php echo $stid3 ; ?>""><img src="<?php echo $img[2] ; ?>" width="100" height="150" border="0" alt=""><br />
             <?php echo $name3 ; ?>
            </a><br></td>
            <td><a href="friendsprofile.php?fid=<?php echo $stid4 ; ?>""><img src="<?php echo $img[3] ; ?>" width="100" height="150" border="0" alt=""><br />
              <?php echo $name4 ; ?>
            </a><br></td>

        </tr>
        </table>
      <table width="100%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col"><br />            &nbsp;     <?php echo $fname. " " . $lname; ?></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <?php if(isset($cname)) { ?><td colspan="2"><strong>College Name : </strong><b><?php echo $cname ; ?></b></td> <?php } ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <?php if(isset($fmes)) { ?><td width="51%"><strong>City :<?php echo $_GET["fmes"]; ?></strong></td><?php } ?>

        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="23"><strong>State:</strong></td>
        <?php if(isset($state)) { ?><td><?php echo $state; ?></td><?php } ?>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="23"><strong>Pincode:</strong></td>
        <?php if(isset($pincode)) { ?><td><?php echo $pincode; ?></td><?php } ?>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="23"><strong>Country:</strong></td>
        <?php if(isset($country)) { ?><td><?php echo $country; ?></td><?php } ?>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
      <td height="23" colspan="2" background="" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong><u>My friends</u></strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="14%" height="23" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center" valign="top"><img src="<?php echo $img[0] ; ?>" alt="" width="71" height="53" /></td>
    <td width="15%" height="23" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center" valign="top"><img src="<?php echo $img[1] ; ?>" alt="" width="71" height="53" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="4" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><img src="<?php echo $img[2] ; ?>" alt="" width="71" height="53" /><br />      
      <br /></td>
    <td height="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center" valign="top"><img src="<?php echo $img[3] ; ?>" alt="" width="71" height="53" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="21" colspan="2" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong><a href="viewall.php">View all</a></strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="36" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center"><img src="images/alosious.jpg" alt="" width="77" height="75" /></td>
    <td height="36" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center"><img src="images/alvas.jpg" alt="" width="96" height="96" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="36" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center"><img src="images/canara.jpg" alt="" width="78" height="78" /></td>
    <td height="36" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><img src="images/dhavala.jpg" alt="" width="96" height="74" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center"><strong>View all</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong><u>Advertisement</u></strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center"  ><a href="http://www.admissionopen.com/" ><img src="images/advt.jpg" width="173" height="185" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>


</div>
<center>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: simple variable `$usimg`  not set

Comment: @SatishSharma can you please help me somewhere in detail?

Comment: you are using `$usimg` variable in line `<img src="<?php echo $usimg;?>"...`. but it not set in the page. assign something in `$usimg` before use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
<a href="profile.php"><img src="<?php echo $usimg;?>" alt="" 
width="90" height="106" /></a><br>
```

to this

```
<a href="profile.php">
 <?php if(isset($usimg)) { ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $usimg;?>" alt="" width="90" height="106" />
  <?php } ?>
</a><br>
```

add `isset` function. If userimg exists show the image. You can add an `else` part and show some generic image  in case user do not have an image.

Docs Link: http://www.php.net/isset

Comment: i need some more your help. see i just updated my question.. please have a look

Comment: ok try this  if(isset($row["userid"]) && $row["userid"] != $_SESSION["stuid"] )

Comment: im happy that i was able to help and solve your issue

Comment: please tell me what is undefined index error because i am getting this error on other pages also.

Comment: when you use some array whether it is ain PHP code or you are getting from database, Every array has keys and values. like $arr = array('a'=>'xyz'), in this array a is key and xyz is value. now if you  use echo $arr['a']. it will echo the value xyz but if you do echo $arr['b'] you will get undefined index array

Comment: Or normally  when we get some array from DB this issue occurs so solution to this is that with other if - else conditions use isset as well. that will fix undexfined index issue

Comment: and just an extra information if you use any variables in your code always initialize them on top before using so you will not get undefined variable issue in future some time.